# How to read Heroku's nested process.env vars / object in nconf?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, heroku-postgres, nconf

I'm trying to deploy Ghost 1.2.0 to Heroku. With previous versions of Ghost (<= 0.11.x), they used a `config.js` file where you could just do:

```
database: {  
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
        host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
        user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
        password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
        port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT
    },
    debug: false
}, …
```

But in this version they're using [`nconf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf) that replaces this `config.js` for environment dependent JSON files like `config.production.json`.

JSON files unlike JS objects can't have vars as values. I could hardcode my credentials to the JSON file, but I don't want to do that because:

1. Looks like a bad practise to me, and
2. *Heroku rotates credentials periodically and updates applications where this database is attached.* (Quoted from Heroku)

After some digging into `nconf` [README](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf/blob/master/README.md) and [issues](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf/issues) I understood that it would be possible to imitate this expected `database` object just with:

```
nconf.env({                                                                                                            
    separator: '__' // Two dashes
});
```

and defining vars as:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE__CLIENT=postgres
heroku config:set DATABASE__CONNECTION__HOST=<value>
...
```

but, no matter what, I get `undefined` when I later call:

```
nconf.get('database');
nconf.get('DATABASE'); // In case it was case-sensitive...
```

Instead, if I call:

```
nconf.get('DATABASE__CLIENT'); // postgres
```

it works. I could try (and I will) to modify Ghost scripts to read all variables this way, but as long as it expects a `database` object it'll be so cool to get it working the right way.

So, has anybody figured out how to correctly recreate an object with Heroku's env vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution.

Unless you want to modify `nconf.env(settings)` like:

```
nconf.env({                                                                                                            
    separator: '__', // Two dashes
    lowerCase: true
});
```

> This will make it possible to pass `lowerCase: true` to `env()` so that if an environment variable is called SOMETHING or SOMEthing, it will also be gettable using something [[Source](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf/pull/177#issue-98942822)]

I recommend to use already lowercase env vars.

So,

```
heroku config:set database__client=postgres
```

will be readable using:

```
nconf.get('database:client');
```

Looks like `nconf` has a different character separator to define nested variables called `separator` and another one to read them called `logicalSeparator` (its default value is `:`)